# How to plot a hline with closing price of latest candle using pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

How to plot a `hline` with closing price of latest candle using pine script? If I provide close as input to `hline` it is giving below error:

```
study("CP-ATR",overlay=true)
cpatr = close-atr(14)
plot(cpatr)
hline(close, title="Zero", color=color.gray, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
```

> line 8: Cannot call 'hline' with arguments (series[float], title=literal string, color=const color, linestyle=const integer); available overloads: hline(input float, const string, input color, input integer, input integer, const bool, string) => hline

Comment: I'm having the same problem. As far as I'm aware, there is no way to convert a series[float] to a float. You can, however, convert it to a string, and when doing that I can see that the variable in question is a perfectly reasonable number which hline should be able to accept. But because you can't cast a series[float] to a float, despite there being only one object in the series, I think this is not possible. :(

Answer (score 2):

`hline` function does not accept series as a source, only constant/input.

To plot a horizontal line from close series you can try the `plot` function and define the `trackprice` and `show_last` arguments as in the example below:

```
//@version=4
study("CP-ATR",overlay=true) 
cpatr = close-atr(14) 
plot(cpatr) 
plot(close, title="Zero", color=color.gray, trackprice = true, show_last = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to plot series of data, i want to plot a horizontal line at closing price - ATR of latest daily candle.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `line.new()` function.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (CP-ATR)", overlay=true)
cpatr = close-atr(14)
plot(cpatr)
//hline(close, title="Zero", color=color.gray, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)

line ln = na
line.delete(ln[1])
ln := line.new(bar_index - 1, cpatr, bar_index, cpatr, width=2, color=color.gray, extend=extend.both, style=line.style_dashed)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at how TV provide channels, such as Keltner Channels, you would see they are using plot function to convert series to constant/int/float.

Here's a workaround. It doesn't show a line but it does what you are looking for, hopefully.

```
cpatr = close-atr(14)
h=plot(cpatr)
fill(h,h, title="Zero", color=color.gray)
```